# Fourier series expansion combined with Gaussian process regression

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process

I'm looking to construct a surrogate model for a 3-dimensional problem ($\phi$, $\theta$, L), where the first paramater $\phi$ is 2$\pi$-periodic. For this reason, I would like to apply a Fourier series expansion for this variable. However, for $\theta$ and $L$ I want to apply Gaussian process regression.

If I were to apply for example a linear regression model for $\theta$ and $L$ then its clear to me how to proceed (basically tensor-products of the two models i.e. something like $f(\phi,\theta,L) = (\sum_{j=1}^N c_j e^{j\phi})\hat{f}(\theta,L)$, where $c$ are the Fourier coefficients and $\hat{f}$ is the linear model). However, when using Gaussian process regression, it is not clear to me how (or even if) this is possible.

What I'm looking for is any insights into this question or preferably some relevant articles/books.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Gaussian processes for periodic parameters or existence of tensor products?

Comment: Hi. Basically I want to know if it is possible to replace $\hat{f}$ in my question by a Gaussian process regression model?